# How can I have a definite number of enemies(ex.10 only) randomly spawned outside of screen then going inside?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

This is the orbivoid tutorial GameScene.m. So my problem is that, enemies spawning is just located somewhere in the lower left due to the CGPointMake. I want to make them already spawned outside of the screen at the start of the game with a definite number, randomly located(ex. 10 enemies already spawned outside of the screen at different locations). Can somebody please help me (some code, tips or something to implement for this)? I did not change anything in the GameScene.m so for the convenience of those who wants to help me. Thanks!

```
@implementation GameScene
    {
        BOOL _dead;
        SKNode *_player;
        NSMutableArray *_enemies;
        SKLabelNode *_scoreLabel;
    }


    -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];


        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;


        _enemies = [NSMutableArray new];

        _player = [SKNode node];
        SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode node];

circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(-10, -10, 20, 20)].CGPath;`
        circle.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        circle.glowWidth = 5;

        SKEmitterNode *trail = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Trail"];
        trail.targetNode = self;
        trail.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circle.frame), CGRectGetMidY(circle.frame));
        _player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
        _player.physicsBody.mass = 100000;
        _player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionPlayer;
        _player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionEnemy;




        [_player addChild:trail];

        _player.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);

        [self addChild:_player];


    }
    return self;
}

    - (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(spawnEnemy) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        }

    -(void)spawnEnemy
    {
        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Spawn.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        SKNode *enemy = [SKNode node];

        SKEmitterNode *trail = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Trail"];
        trail.targetNode = self;
        trail.particleScale /= 2;
        trail.position = CGPointMake(10, 10);
        trail.particleColorSequence = [[SKKeyframeSequence alloc] initWithKeyframeValues:@[


[SKColor redColor],
                                                                                        [SKColor colorWithHue:0.1 saturation:.5 brightness:1 alpha:1],
                                                                                        [SKColor redColor],
                                                                                        ] times:@[@0, @0.02, @0.2]];




        [enemy addChild:trail];
    enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:6];
    enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionEnemy;
    enemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;

        enemy.position = CGPointMake(50, 50);

    [_enemies addObject:enemy];
    [self addChild:enemy];

    if(!_scoreLabel) {
    _scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Courier-Bold"];

    _scoreLabel.fontSize = 200;
    _scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
    CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    _scoreLabel.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:1 alpha:0.5];
    [self addChild:_scoreLabel];
    }
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", _enemies.count];



    // Next spawn
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction waitForDuration:5],
        [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnEnemy) onTarget:self],
        ]]];
        }


    -(void)dieFrom: (SKNode*)killingEnemy
    {
    _dead = YES;

    SKEmitterNode *explosion = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Explosion"];
    explosion.position = _player.position;
    [self addChild:explosion];

    [explosion runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Explosion.wav" waitForCompletion:NO],
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4],
        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            // TODO: Revove these more nicely
            [killingEnemy removeFromParent];
            [_player removeFromParent];
        }],
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4],
        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            explosion.particleBirthRate = 0;
            }],
            [SKAction waitForDuration: 1.2],

        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            ORBMenuScene *menu = [[ORBMenuScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
[self.view presentScene:menu transition:[SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:0.4]];
        }],
        ]]];

}


    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    }

    -(void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [_player runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self] duration:.01]];
    }

    -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
    {
        CGPoint playerPos = _player.position;

        for(SKNode *enemyNode in _enemies)
        {
            CGPoint enemyPos = enemyNode.position;

            /* Uniform speed: */
            CGVector diff = TCVectorMinus(playerPos, enemyPos);
            CGVector normalized = TCVectorUnit(diff);
            CGVector force = TCVectorMultiply(normalized, 4);

            [enemyNode.physicsBody applyForce:force];
        }

        _player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake (0, 0);


        }
    -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
    {
        if(_dead)
                return;

        [self dieFrom:contact.bodyB.node];
        contact.bodyB.node.physicsBody = nil;
        }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only an educated guess, since I can’t test my code.
I think in your `didMoveToView` method you can do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    [self performSelector:@selector(spawnEnemy) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

to spawn 10 enemies at once.

In your `spawnEnemy` method you set the position of the enemies similar to this:

```
CGFloat x = arc4random() % 100 + size.width/2;
CGFLoat y = arc4random() % (int)size.height;

if (arc4random() % 2 == 0)
    x = size.width/2 + x;
else
    x = size.width/2 - x;

enemy.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

This should spawn the enemies beyond the left and right side of the screen, but within 100 points of the edge of the screen.
Of course you need to tweak this to your needs.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! but I also wanted to maintain the 10 enemies. How can I stop it from respawning if it has already 10 enemies on screen? Thanks again!

Comment: At the end of spawnEnemy remove the code followed by '//Next spawn'.
Also, if this worked for you, please "accept" my answer, so other people can see that this worked.